# How to configure Emacs for literate programming?

Tags: emacs

I would like to use Emacs for literate programming.

I want my code to look like [this](http://en.literateprograms.org/Huffman_coding_%28C_Plus_Plus%29#chunk%20use%3aclass%20Hufftree%20definition) .

```
<<class Hufftree definition>>=
template<typename DataType, typename Frequency> class Hufftree
{
public:
  Hufftree public members
private:
  Hufftree private members
};
```

In org-babel I can't give names to my code snippets which are spread all over the document and collect them together as shown below. Whenever I compile I want the tool to automatically insert `<<member functions>>` wherever I refer them.

```
Some text here. Blah blah...

<<my foo class>> ==
#+begin_src ruby 
class Foo{
    <<member functions>>
}
#+end_src

Something random to say about some other things. 

<<member functions>> ==
#+begin_src 
// code for member functions goes here 
#+end_src
```

Comment: I might help if you include what you want to do in your question rather than just linking it. It would also help if you provide an example of what you want to achieve and include how far you have gotten in achieving that.

Comment: It would also help if you describe what you didn't like about `org-babel` because AFAIK it's easiest way to do literate programming.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Noweb](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/), which allows literate programming in almost any language with LaTeX or [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/)/[reStructuredText](http://docutils.sf.net/) syntax; you can see an [example here](http://inmabb.criba.edu.ar/varios/noweb-sphinx/wc.html)).

You could then use the standard Emacs LaTeX writing facilities and maybe mix with [a multiple-major mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes) to edit the code portions.